# Raspberry pi - file blocking startup

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, recovery

I was trying to make some script automatically run on OS start up, but somehow i did it wrong and now i cant even start the OS since the file is blocking it.

Can i recover the OS removing what i did or at least have access to all my files inside my SD card? I've opened it on my laptop and all i have is two repartitions "BOOT" and "RECOVER" but can't find my user folder `/home` or anything usefull.

What i did:

```
sudo cp /home/pi/Desktop/test.sh /etc/rc.local
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best get a bootable CD of a linux distro - fedora, ubuntu, any other, it doesn't really matter - boot the CD on your laptop and mount the SD card from there. Windows can't read linux partitions; other linuxes can.